# Camera.open() is not working android

Tags: camera, android

I am trying to write a custom camera application in android.
For that I need to open the camera application.

for that i am tring following code..

> Camera camera = Camera.open();

but is showing error like

> method open undefined for type Camera

i did as suggested here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)

any suggestion..

Thanks,
Ravindra Gupta

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You most likely imported the wrong camera class at the top of your source file, which is `android.graphics.Camera`.

You need `android.hardware.Camera` instead.

Thanks

Comment: thanks i put import android.hardware.Camera and it worked after that.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have not added the camera permission. See below - you need to add this in your manifest;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports. I had a similar problem and the Camera object Eclipse chose for me was: `import android.graphics.Camera;` instead it should be: `import android.hardware.Camera;`

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above work: 
check to see if you are requesting camera permission manually. Newer Android permissions (API > 23) are set at runtime, not install time. 
See: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Please create a variable like this:

```
android.hardware.Camera camera ;
```

and then try open method :

```
camera = camera.open();
```

// this is working on my android studio

Answer (score 0):

I have Faced the same problem till i reached that older versions of android will work properly until Android Marshmallow  so it needs a runtime permission in order to proceed and show the camera ... 
you can read about it in this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

for me i used a 3rd party library to do all this stuff for me  from this link and all resolved .. 
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2804 
Hope it helps

Comment: Could you expand your answer? The link itself is not considered a good answer.

Comment: in old android versions you can just in manifest add the camera permission then it works ... now you have to request the permission in the runtime and show dialogue for the user and then you can do Camera camera = Camera.open(); in the overrides method onActivityResult. then it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a lot of issues while using integrating camera native/camera2 api. The code was bulky. To avoid complexity and compatibility issues google provide new CameraX api in new android jetpack library. See the google provided documentation https://developer.android.com/training/camerax. There is also a Kotlin based library i found on github https://github.com/robertlevonyan/CameraXDemo. You can get more clearity with less code.

Answer (score 0):

Waged right!!!
A permission request is required. And I found the right code. he works.
I advise you to look at this article to initially connect the camera:
https://habr.com/ru/post/112272/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZgP.png)

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 15); }
```